# ReactiveCocoa apply same properties on multiple objects

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I don't know if ReactiveCocoa can do that, or if it's one of the right use case for it, basically I want to setups 2 or more views the exact same ways, for instance

```
[self.photoOrVideoLabel setTextColor:[UIColor glInboxGrayTextColor]];
[self.photoOrVideoLabel setFont:[UIFont glProximaNovaRegularWithSize:12.0f]];

[self.writeSomethingLabel setTextColor:[UIColor glInboxGrayTextColor]];
[self.writeSomethingLabel setFont:[UIFont gLBaskervilRegularWithSize:12.0f]];
```

Is there a way with reactiveCocoa to merge them and configure them in the same block ?

Comment: No, you don't need Reactive Cocoa for doing such simple tasks. Reactive Cocoa is a tool to find solutions for complex asynchronous problems. Your problem is neither asynchronous nor complex, and I wouldn't take a deep look into Reactive Cocoa unless you really have a complex asynchronous problem which you cannot solve easily otherwise. ;)

Comment: Yeah I know, I should have stated I use it for much more complicated stuff and I really like it. Now I wanted to knows if there was something I could use for that :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a ReactiveCocoa problem. Just factor out the common code (`-setTextColor:` and `-setFont:`) into a reusable method or block and invoke that twice.

Comment: Yeah thank you, the fact is, I was so exited when testing ReactiveCocoa on a new project that I've tried to solve everything with it, I quickly realised for what it was made for. Still awesome!

Comment: Justin, I am sorry for having disturbed you, but I couldn't find another way to connect. Can you please look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576833/what-is-a-correct-alternative-for-subscribing-to-signals-in-reactivecocoa-for-ne
? I hope you will advice some good practice for this common problem. Because I couldn't find any info about this. Great thanks in advance!