# What is a correct alternative for subscribing to signals in ReactiveCocoa for network calls?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, afnetworking, reactive-cocoa

I'm new to `ReactiveCocoa` world and after reading best practices of ReactiveCocoa [here](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md#avoid-explicit-subscriptions-and-disposal) I knew that I need to `"avoid explicit subscriptions and disposal"` but in all tutorials about network and `ReactiveCocoa` I saw the same pattern : create signal (make `GET` or `POST` request to server, parse result, `sendNext`, `sendCompleted`) -> `subcsribeNext` (do UI stuff or something other with the result) -> `subscribeError`. So as we see there is an explicit subscription here, which is not good, I think.

Are there some more correct and conceptually pure ways of doing this common thing? `rac_liftSelector:withSignals:` or something like this? Or when we deal with network calls and `AFNetworking` we should always use this standard subscription pattern? Detailed explanation will be very helpful.

**EDITS:**

In my application I have mainly fetching calls, some of them are dependent and others are single (vast majority) like `login` or `fetchWhatever`, or `postWhatever`. All API calls I construct with the same pattern like this (`self` - is my `API manager` `NVMAPI` class which is `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass):

```
    -(RACSignal*)loginUserWithEmail:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password
     {
        __block NSURLSessionDataTask* task;
        return [[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        task = [self GET:kUserLoginEndpoint
          parameters:@{@"email": email, @"password": password}
             success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                     NVMUser* user = [[NVMUser alloc] initWithDictionary:responseObject[@"user"]];
                   [subscriber sendNext:user];
                   [subscriber sendCompleted];
             } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                 [subscriber sendError:error];
             }];
    return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
        [task cancel];
    }];
       }] replayLazily];
        }
```

I don't use `MVVM` and use simple MVC. Here how I make API calls and create signals in view controllers:

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Processing..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
[[[NVMAPI api] loginUserWithEmail:self.emailTextField.text
                               andPassword:self.passwordTextField.text]    
 subscribeNext:^(id x) {
                [self.activeUser setupWithUser:x];
                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kLoginSeque sender:self];
 } 
     error:^(NSError *error) {
             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
             [self showAlertWithText:error.localizedDescription title:@"Error"];
 }];
```

All signals I use the same way like: `fetchComments`, `postStatus`, etc. If I have dependent calls I use `flattenMap`. So I'm interested - is it a right approach for creating signals and for using them (simple `subscribeNext`)? Or this can be achieved with some more correct and elegant way?

**EDIT 2:**

Main problem with subscriptions which I see - I don't know how to implement pagination for tableview with them. I have `fetchComment` method with load paginated comments - each page contain 15 comments. I can't use neither `subcribeNext` nor `RAC()` binding for this, right?How can I manage this pattern?

Comment: Do you have some sample code that you'd specifically like to see reworked? A lot of this stuff is hard to talk about in the abstract, so understand how a real world algorithm changes can be really beneficial.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers Thanks for the response!. Please see my edits. I write code samples of how I apply my approach in my application.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers I also added the main problem which I encountered.

Comment: Why do you say you can't use `-subscribeNext:` to fetch each page of comments? You can do just about anything you want in that subscription block, including update the views that display comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network calls aren't special, you can compose signals that issue network requests the same way you would compose any other signal.

Comment: @HarryDeveloper1212 To expand on what Erik is saying here, anything that applies to any other signal (like `rac_liftSelector:withSignals:`) applies just as much to a signal that makes a network request. You can `-catch:` it, include it in `-flattenMap:`, or do whatever else to incorporate it into a signal chain, ultimately ending with a lift or a `RAC()` binding if you want to avoid subscription.